# SQL Possible syntax error using LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql-like

Got SQL Error, believe it is located near the `LIKE` statement, but not entirely sure why.

```
SELECT submit_time                                              AS datetime, 
       Max(IF(field_name = 'first-name', field_value, NULL))    AS fName, 
       Max(IF(field_name = 'submission_id', field_value, NULL)) AS id
FROM   wp_cf7dbplugin_submits 
WHERE  form_name = 'Personal Info' 
  AND ( Max(IF(field_name = 'submission_id', field_value, '')) LIKE '%4%' ) 
GROUP  BY submit_time 
ORDER  BY Max(IF(field_name = 'submission_id', field_value, '')) DESC 
LIMIT  0, 40
```

Are you not able to use `LIKE` like that?  How to rewrite this query?

[image: Database Table snapshot]

Please note:  `submit_time` is not always different.  `submit_time` refers to the time that the form was submitted and it holds many other `field_name` rows besides `submission_id`.  Also `field_value` is of type `varchar`, so it's a string despite holding an integer value.

Comment: Can you post the error, please?

Comment: A wordpress database error:  `WordPress database error Invalid use of group function for query`

Comment: You cannot use aggregate functions, like `MAX`, in WHERE clauses; only `SELECT` and `HAVING` (and _maybe_ `ORDER BY`).

Comment: `ORDER BY` is fine I believe.  How can I rewrite this query to get past this error but have the same outcome?

Comment: Try replacing `MAX(IF(field_name = 'submission_id', field_value, ''))` with `id` - you're doing that work in the field list, should be able to reference it in the where and order.

Comment: No, that does not work, `Unknown column 'id'`

Comment: As @Uueerdo say you cant use `MAX()`  on your where. Maybe if you explain what you want to do we can help you. But create a simple version. Create some sample data and expected output. I will delete some field I belive wont affect your question. [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have created pagination and am trying to provide a means to search a group of rows from the database where `field_name = 'submission_id'` and it is not null.  So I need to use `MAX` here.

Comment: Sorry, since you're doing `MAX()` to create the id, you'll need to move that condition to a `having` clause.

Comment: How is that possible when using `LIKE`?

Comment: Your problem isnt the `LIKE` is the `MAX` again show us sample data and expected output so we know how fix it. Right know not sure if you want remove the `%4%` before the `group by` for that you can use `CASE` or after the `group by` and can use `HAVING` But please small sample not those 10 columns you have before

Comment: I'm just trying to grab all values that are `LIKE '%4%'` that is found within the id.  There are multiple rows with the same `submit_time` so I don't need them, only need the rows defined for the submit_time where the field_name = 'first-name', etc. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to use a group function in a part of the query that is used before grouping happens. You need to move that condition to a having clause. Also, since you're already performing the `MAX(IF(...))` operation in the select, you can reference that field:

```
SELECT submit_time AS datetime,
  ...,
  MAX(IF(field_name = 'submission_id', field_value, NULL)) AS id,
  ...
FROM wp_cf7dbplugin_submits
WHERE form_name = 'Personal Info'
GROUP BY submit_time
HAVING id LIKE '%4%'
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 40
```